Mac Screen turns on after lock screen after Teamviewer was installed
I have the issue that when I lock my screen. Then after the screens "turns off" it turns back on.
This has started to happen after I had teamviewer installed.
Is there away to get rid of this behavior?
I did uninstall TeamViewer, but it seems like something was left behind.
I cannot find it in Activity Monitor.

There is a "Preventing Sleep" column in the Energy tab in Activity Monitor, have you checked that nothing prevents sleep?

I will check when I get home thanks :)

Keep me informed! :)

@Thinkr thank you teamviewer had left something behind and it could be seen in the energy tab

The Energy tab of the Activity Monitor has a column called "Preventing Sleep", it's likely that the process causing the problem you're experiencing will be listed there as "Yes". You can just force quit that process if it's troubling you.

